# How to make a button disabled when no text is in a textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need the buttons `BtnCalculate` and `BtnMessageBox` to be disabled when there is nothing in the `TxtQuantity` and `TxtPrice` Text boxes including when the program starts. Does anyone know how to do this? Obviously the "Quantity and price must not be empty" message will not be needed in the code anymore after changes are made. Thank you very much in advance! May be simple but IDK what I am doing.

Here is the CODE:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BtnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //declare Variables
        int intQuantity;
        Decimal decPrice;
        Decimal decTotal;
        //make sure quantity and price are the same
        // if string is null or empty retuern textbox

        Decimal TAX_RATE = 0.06m;
        if (OosTax.Checked == true)
            { TAX_RATE = 0.09m; }
        if ((TxtQuantity.Text.Trim().Length == 0 || (TxtPrice.Text == "")))
        { MessageBox.Show("Quantity and price must not be empty", "Calculator", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2); }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                intQuantity = Int32.Parse(TxtQuantity.Text);
                decPrice = Decimal.Parse(TxtPrice.Text);
                decTotal = (intQuantity * decPrice) * (1 + TAX_RATE);
                LblMessage.Text = decTotal.ToString("C");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { // Send Focus to Quantity
                TxtQuantity.Focus();
                TxtQuantity.SelectAll();
            }
        }
    }

    private void BtnMessageBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //declare Variables
        int intQuantity;
        Decimal decPrice;
        Decimal decTotal;
        string message = "Your Total Is: ";
        Decimal TAX_RATE = 0.06m;
        if (OosTax.Checked == true)
        { TAX_RATE = 0.09m; }
        //make sure quantity and price are the same
        // if string is null or empty retuern textbox

        if ((TxtQuantity.Text.Trim().Length == 0 || (TxtPrice.Text == "")))
        { MessageBox.Show("Quantity and price must not be empty", "Calculator", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2); }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                intQuantity = Int32.Parse(TxtQuantity.Text);
                decPrice = Decimal.Parse(TxtPrice.Text);
                decTotal = (intQuantity * decPrice) * (1 + TAX_RATE);
                // Display Total Currency as
                MessageBox.Show(message + System.Environment.NewLine + decTotal.ToString("C"), "Chapter Two",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { // Send Focus to Quantity
                TxtQuantity.Focus();
                TxtQuantity.SelectAll();
            }

        }
    }

    private void BtnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void BtnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LblMessage.Text = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use TextChanged event on textbox

like this

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = (textBox1.Text.Length > 0);
    }
```

if you wish to do this on window loaded,

use

```
textBox1_TextChanged(null,null);
```

on loaded event

Comment: This makes it so the calculate button is disabled at startup, but does not reenable the button when text is entered into the textbox.

Comment: if then, try to change event as KeyDown or KeyUp. it'll be better method to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would just write a method that sets the button enabled property based on the textbox text length of the two textbox controls, and then call it from the form Load event and the TextChanged event of the textboxes:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ButtonEnabler();
}

private void txtPrice_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ButtonEnabler();
}

private void txtQuantity_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ButtonEnabler();
}

private void ButtonEnabler()
{
    bool enabled = txtPrice.TextLength > 0 && txtQuantity.TextLength > 0;
    btnCalculate.Enabled = enabled;
    btnMessageBox.Enabled = enabled;
}
```

Comment: This does not work. The textbox is still enabled when opening the form, and when there is no text in it. Are there any other modifications I should make to fix this? Thanks,

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on the `bool enabled` line ,can you examine the values of the `TextLength` properties? They should be `0` if there is no text. It works great on my sample form.

Comment: Oh, I just made an edit - it was only disabling them if both fields were empty, I've made it so it will be disabled if either field is empty now.